# Why is my mean test score at parameter tuning (cv) lower than on hold out test set (RandomForestClassifier)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, cross-validation, hyperparameters

I'm doing hyperparameter tuning using `RandomizedSearchCV` (sklearn) with a 3 fold cross validation on my training set. After that I'm checking my score (accuracy, recall_weighted, cohen_kappa) on the test set. Surprisingly its always a bit higher than the best_score attribute of my `RandomizedSearchCV`.

In the beginning I'm performing a stratified data split into 70/30 training and testing sets.

My dataset includes 12 classes, 12 features and is imbalanced. I have ~3k datapoints.

Is it normal (or not too surprising) when I compare the cross validation training score of the parameter tuning with the score on a hold out test set?

I already tried different random seeds for the initial split and different scoring methods (accuracy, recall_macro, recall_weighted, cohen_kappa).

Here is my code:

```
#Split data in training and test set (70/30 stratified split)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_Distances, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, stratify=Y, shuffle=True)

#Scorings used for parameter tuning evaluation
scoring = {'Accuracy' : make_scorer(accuracy_score), 'Recall' : 'recall_weighted', 'Kappa' : make_scorer(cohen_kappa_score)}

#Initializing of parameter ranges
params_randomSearch = {"min_samples_leaf": np.arange(1,30,2),
              "min_samples_split": np.arange(2,20,2),
              "max_depth": np.arange(2, 20, 2),
              "min_weight_fraction_leaf": np.arange(0. ,0.4, 0.1),
              "n_estimators": np.arange(10, 1000, 100),
              "max_features" : ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2', None],
              "criterion" : ['entropy', 'gini']}

#Perform RandomSearchCV over a wide range of possible parameters
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rs = RandomizedSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42), param_distributions=params_randomSearch, scoring = scoring, cv = 3, refit = 'Recall', n_iter=60, n_jobs=-1, random_state=42)
    rs.fit(x_train, y_train)
    print('Best Score: ', rs.best_score_, '\nBest parameters: ', rs.best_params_)
    y_predict = rs.best_estimator_.predict(x_test)
    acc = recall_score(y_test, y_predict, average='weighted')
```

Results for recall_weighted:

```
# RandomizedSearchCV:
best_params_ = {dict} {'n_estimators': 310, 'min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.0, 'min_samples_split': 12, 'min_samples_leaf': 5, 'max_features': 'auto', 'max_depth': 14, 'criterion': 'entropy'}
best_score_ = {float64} 0.5103216514642342

# Hold out test set:
0.5666293393057111
```

I want to use the hold-out test set to compare how different algorithms work on this data set.

**Question**: Is there an error in my approach leading to this difference in score or can I ignore it and how should I interpret it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i can see everything is as expected.

*best_score_* gives you the average score of 3 folds for the best estimator:

Each fold contains ~**1.386** training samples: 3.000 * 0.7 (train size) * 2/3 (cv train size).

Then you fit the best estimator (This is caused by "refit" parameter of RandomizedSearchCV) on entire x_train, which has ~**2.100** samples: 3.000 * 0.7, which is much more.

You can try, for example, cv=5 for your search and you would probably see that the score difference decreases.

Also the more data you have - the more representative the CV score is. Maybe for this particular project 3000 samples is not quite enough.

Comment: Thanks! Does `RandomSearchCV` automatically fit the best_estimator on the entire x_train? That would explain a lot. I thought its just the training partition of the cv.

Comment: You do it explicitly with rs.fit(x_train, y_train). RandomSearchCV  itself just choses the best parameters with CV.

Comment: But it does cross validation with 3 folds doesn't it? I don't fit the `best_estimator` as far as I can tell. I thought the `best_estimator` is trained with 0.7*2/3 data points

Comment: In the source code of RandomSearchCV we see "refit" parameter: refit : boolean, default=True
        Refit the best estimator with the entire dataset.
        If "False", it is impossible to make predictions using
        this RandomizedSearchCV instance after fitting. So after the best estimator is found, "fit" method refits it with the entire x_train by default.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. So everything works I guess. Do you think this is a valid approach? In the end I want to use the prediction score on the test set to compare different algorithms (boosting etc.). I also have an oversampled dataset with 8k datapoints which is balanced.

Comment: Because the amount of data i would use several train/holdout splits with different(but fixed) random seeds and averaging holdout scores. Comparing models with this average can be more stable in my opinion. Also with several thousands of examples itd not be computationally expensive.